# How to set ReSharper variable naming rules so that it allows underscores?

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, resharper, naming, rules

Whenever I use a variable name that stands for a primary key as

```
int pk_MyObject = GetPrimaryKey(myObject)
```

ReSharper complains about the pk_MyObject and offers me to rename it pkMyObject.

**How can I add a new rule to ReSharper so that it does not complain about variable names such as xx_YYYYY** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper > Options > Languages > C# > C# Naming Style > Override Custom Settings and then edit the entities you'd like.

Note: This is based on ReSharper 5.1. If you're running a different version the menu items might be named differently, but it should be possible to do since 4.5

Also, see this question [How to use bdd naming style with Resharper 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757381/how-to-use-bdd-naming-style-with-resharper-4-5)